# Unity3d Facebook SDK: properties on iOS don't get published

Tags: facebook, sdk, unity-game-engine, facebook-unity-sdk

we are working on share functionality for our unity game using the Facebook Unity SDK.
We are using FB.Feed for our post and share additional links at the end of the post using the 'properties' parameter and sending a Dictionary.

This works nicely on Android and for the webplayer but nothing is shown when using the iOS version which has the exact same codebase.

[image: screenshot of post]

This seems to be a bug since the same happens using the interactive console example.
Can anyone confirm?
Is there an official forum for the FB Unity SDK? The beta goup on facebook seems to be dead.....

Help very appreciated.

Simon

Comment: I just found out that in IOSFacebook.cs the 'properties' don't get added to the object/call:

iosFeedRequest(System.Convert.ToInt32(AddFacebookDelegate(callback)), toId, link, linkName, linkCaption, linkDescription, picture, mediaSource, actionName, actionLink, reference);

In AndroidFacebook.cs they are added.

Comment: Facebook bug report tracking this:  https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/463969720388978

Comment: Can you please add the facebook-unity-sdk tag to this?  That will help us and other people find out about this problem.

Answer (score 0):

We are deprecating the properties functionality.  Just so you know, for your specific use case  the properties are unnecessary.  We will automatically send users to the Google Play store when they click your game's link on Android and the iTunes store when they click it on iOS.

Comment: This only works if the user uses the facebook app right now. If he uses the mobile browser he'll land on the canvas app page.

Comment: Great catch, we are going to fix that bug.